# Karate Retry until unable to parse through if my response is 2 levels down - response.. instead of response

Tags: karate

In one of the API calls I have, there is an assertions that goes like this

- match response..count == [1]
  Reason for response.. is because its 2 levels down and I cannot pass the first level value because its a UUID and the value is not static

If i pass

- retry until response..count == '1'
  It doesnt work and I cant seem to find a solution for this. I need retry until because there is a delay and I have to do multiple retries.

Any help is appreciated

Tried this

- retry until response..count == '1'

Was expecting it to retry until the count is 1, the test fails instead